# Ember ajax DELETE call from different port getting " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: ajax, ember.js, http-headers, cors

I have an Ember application and I am trying to do a DELETE request on 'click' from a component (sent to the route).  The server is on a different port than the User interface.

This is the ajax request on the route:

```
         deleteAlert(alert) {
            let self = this;
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: 'http://example.com:4320/data/alerts/' + alert.id,
                type: 'DELETE',
                beforeSend: function(request)
                {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","example.com:4301");
                    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,PUT");
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.status==='Success!') {
                        Ember.Logger.log(response);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    Ember.Logger.error(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR);
                }
            });
```

I am getting the following error, however:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:4320/data/alerts/252. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com:4301' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I have also tried adding "*" to the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header as well as defining the headers in the following way (outside the beforeSend function):

```
          deleteAlert(alert) {
            let self = this;
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: 'http://example.com:4320/data/alerts/' + alert.id,
                type: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://example.com:4301',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,PUT',
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.status==='Success!') {
                        Ember.Logger.log(response);
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    Ember.Logger.error(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR);
                }
            });
```

Same error.

Is this something that needs to be fixed on the server-side?  I have no problems with POST or GET requests, just DELETE so far.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Different ports mean different origins, that's why it's complaining. It is indeed something you need to fix server-side, try checking out the resources at http://enable-cors.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with Ember, since I had no issues with other methods (GET, POST).  I simply changed the API method to POST and had no issues with it using it like that.  This is probably not the best solution, more of a work-around.
I'm sure Ember wouldn't have a problem with DELETE call if I had used Ember Data.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "example.com:4301");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,PUT");
```

These headers are not for client! Your server need to set these headers.

Add these permissions to your api server. (which is served at example.com:4320)